# convert DataGridView Contents to Excel using SpreadSheetLight in C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, spreadsheetlight

so i'm trying to export the contents in a `DataGridView` to an `Excel` File. And for me to do this, i am using [`SpreadSheetLight`](http://spreadsheetlight.com) for C#. But as far as reading the Sample Codes and Tutorials go, they're only demonstrating manual Excel content creation:

```
using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
{
    sl.SetCellValue("B3", "It costs what for a Jimmy Choo?!?");
    sl.SaveAs("MahNewShoes.xlsx");
}
```

but what i want to achieve is to convert a whole DataGridView into SpreadSheetLight's Excel. If i am using a loop and loop the whole rows and columns of the DataGridView, how is it possible to set the Columns to `A, B, C ... AA, BB, CC` given that the loop uses integers ?.

hoping someone can give me a walk through here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i= 0;
SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();

foreach (DataRow row in dtTransfer.Rows)
{
  sl[i, 0].SetCellValue("It costs what for a Jimmy Choo?!?");
  sl.SaveAs("MahNewShoes.xlsx");
  i++;
}
```

Comment: is `0` = column ?. how would you increment it ? given that `Column 0` in Excel is `A` ?

Comment: You can add any variable as int j = 0 and increment it into the foreach

Comment: yes, but would `SpreadSheetLight` automatically convert int j to excel's column ? lets say j = 26, then it would be `Column Z` in Excel right ?

Comment: Yes sure. But j=25 will be as Z

Comment: By the way you can use Aspose.dll too it is very easy. Say me you email address I will send you this dll for exporting to excell

Comment: my only concern was the Columns since excel uses alphabet incrementation like `A, B, C .. AA, AB, AC` instead of numeric incrementation like `1, 2, 3 .. 27, 28, 29` which is the value of the counter in loops

Comment: you can send it to my public mail at `sof@skyenginetechnologies.xyz` thanks :)

Comment: No your offset must be only from 0. It is the one of the basis rules of the excel.

Comment: i think i'm getting the hang of it. i'll try it first. thanks you :)

Comment: I have sent you. Don't forget feedback ))

Comment: can you send it again ?. i haven't received it yet. thanks

Comment: Give me another email. It is returned.I will try to send again